# Let $G$ be a group and $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$, $G_p \in Syl_p(G)$, where $p$ is an odd prime divisor of $|G|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$, $G_p \in Syl_p(G)$, where $p$ is an odd prime divisor of $|G|$. Suppose that $M/N$ be a maximal subgroup of $G_pN/N$. then $M = PN$ for some maximal subgroup $P$ of $G_p$.

thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you need help with?  Can you show us how far you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G_p N/N$ is a $p$-group, thus maximality of $M/N$ implies $[G_p N/N : M/N] = [G_p N : M] = p$. Then the order of $M$ is exactly $|G_p N| / p$. Thus if you take a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $M$, it is necessarily a maximal subgroup of $G_p$. You already know that $N\subset M$, thus $PN=M$.

Comment: $P$ necessarily a maximal subgroup of $G_p$. can explain more. thanks

Comment: Well, first of all $G_p$ is not contained in $M$ since otherwise $M$ contains both $G_p$ and $N$, which leads to a contradiction ($M$ is proper in $G_p N$). Then $G_pM$ contains $M$ properly, which implies $G_p M=G_p N$ by maximality of $M$. Then $p = [G_p M : M] = [G_p : G_p\cap M]$, so $G_p\cap M$ is proper in $G_p$ with index $p$. Thus $G_p\cap M$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $M$. By the way I didn't use minimal normality of $N$ and $p$ is an odd prime, thus I suspect my proof a lot.

Comment: why $G_p M=G_p N$?

Comment: Because $M$ is maximal, $G_p M = M$ or $G_p M = G_p N$. The former case leads to a contradiction since it implies $G_p \subset M$.

Comment: I'm Confused.can you explain more?

$M \leq G_pN \leq G_pM$ and $M$ maximal subgroup of $G_pN$. is it correct؟

How $G_p M = G_p N$ or $M=G_pM$.

thanks

Comment: No, $M$ is a subgroup of $G_p N$, so is $G_p$. Thus $G_p M\subseteq G_p N$. Since $M$ is maximal in $G_p N$, we can say that $G_p M$ is either $M$ or $G_p N$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be the projection morphism of a group $G$ in a group
quotient $G / H$. then the map $p^{-1}$  from the set of all
subgroup  in $G / H$ to the set of  all subgroups of $G$
containing $H$ that is  $\{KH, K< G\}$, which  for $L$ associated
$p^{-1}(L) = \cup_{\overline{x}\in L} \overline{x}$,  and  this
map is a bijection that preserves indices ie $[G / H: L] = [G: p
(L)]$ as $[G / H: HK / H] = [G: HK]$ (by third isomorphism theorem
of groups ).

So as $N<M$, then $p^{-1}p (M) = M$  and the  index  of $M/N$ in a
$G_pN / N$  equal to the index of $M$ in $G_pN$. so $ $M is a
maximum subgroup of $G_pN$ and  $M = PN$ where $P$ is a maximum
subgroup of $G_p$, (therefore of index $p$).